# onBackPressed remove @Override annotation

Tags: android

i'm using the GreenDroid library at my app and i'm trying to catch/handle the back button here's my code:

```
private Toast toast;
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
     toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", 4000);
     toast.show();
     this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   } else {
      if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel();
      }
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

i'm getting this `@Override` remove annotation problem.If I remove the `@Override` annotation, there's an error at `super.onBackPressed();` and Eclipse says:

> The method onBackPressed is undefined for the type GDActivity.

GDActivity is from the GreenDroid library.

is this because of the library or what?

Comment: Can you go to Project-->Properties--->Java Compiler and can ensure that you are using version 1.6 and not 1.5 ?

Comment: i tried the finish() instead of super.onPressed(); but it returns to login activity. how can i do exit or press back button not going back to the login.class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try this..

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{ 
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) //if it's 1.5
    {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
       {        // do something on back.        
          return true;    
       }  
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Comment: it's working but it returns to login activity. how can i do exit or press back button not going back to the login.class?

Comment: oh, i just copied your code and it works, but i want something like when i pressed the back button twice it should exit the app from the Main.class because i have this Login.class first then after logging in  it will display the Main.class, so if i clicked back button class i want it not to go back to Login.class or something like Login.class fields should be empty.

Comment: Make sure you check the closing braces } before calling onBackPressed. This should be called outside onCreate

Comment: onBackPressed must be defined as an external function outside onCreate. The point where you close onCreate, define onBackPressed there. Then you might not get these errors